# Для чего нужен __init__.py файл и в каких случаях использовать __all__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Есть директория содержащая следующие поддиректории
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ней содержится файл__init__,

```
from .errors import dp
from .users import dp

__all__ = ["dp"]
```

в обеих указанных в файле директориях есть такой же__init__ файл с таким же содержимым
(ниже содержимое __init__файла директории users)

```
from .help import dp
from .start import dp

from .menu_handlers import dp
from .echo import dp

__all__ = ["dp"]
```

Для чего здесь используется__all__ и на что он влияет?

В другой директории в файле__init__ просто импортируется файл из той же директории

```
from . import choice_buttons
```

Что происходит в этом случае и на что это влияет?
Так же, по каким правилам импортируются модули из верхних директорий(директорий содержащих директорию) нужно ли дополнительно прописывать что то в поддиректории при импорте из верхних директорий ?

Если подытожить, у меня есть 3 вопроса:

- Для чего нужен файл **init** и как в нем используется **all**?

  Что    происходит, когда в файл **init** просто импортируются файлы
  из той    же директории?

  Есть ли особые правила для импорта из верхних    директорий ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `__all__` перечислены имена переменных, которые будут импортированы в область видимости модуля при вызове `from package import *`.